# How to reuse controls instances in DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, caching, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I have few layouts (different DataTemplates) with video controls. Creation of this video controls is very long. I want to reuse instances of this video controls in different DataTemplates.

### Farfetched example:

**Codebehind and ViewModel:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Layout1 = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("_layout1");
            Layout2 = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("_layout2");

            DataContext = new ViewModel {Content1 = "Content1", Content2 = "Content2"};
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _view.ContentTemplate = _view.ContentTemplate == Layout1 ? Layout2 : Layout1;
        }

        DataTemplate Layout1;
        DataTemplate Layout2;
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Content1 { get; set; }
        public string Content2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window Name="_mainForm" x:Class="WpfVideo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WpfVideo"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="_layout1" DataType="{x:Type model:ViewModel}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="{Binding Content1}"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding Content2}"/>
        </StackPanel>   
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="_layout2" DataType="{x:Type model:ViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="{Binding Content1}"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding Content2}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Change</Button>
    <ContentPresenter Name="_view" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource _layout1}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**How to reuse Buttons and prevent creation of new buttons on each template change?**

**EDITED:** Used switch between datatemplates _layout1 and _layout2 on Button_click. Only one template active. I don’t want to draw one instance of control in two places. I want to prevent creation of controls in other template when it activated (previous deactivated). 
Or maybe I can use another approach, without datatemplates? Style, resources, triggers?

Comment: It can be done in xaml. Define in resources a ContentControl containing the control you want to share, and use it in data templates loading it as a StaticResource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Controls Pool

```
ControlsPoolControl<T> 
IControlsPool<T>
```

- T – type of reusable control.
- IControlsPool - used to store
  reusable instances of control by key
  object (some property of viewmodel)
- ControlsPoolControl - Container,
  which restore inner control from
  IControlsPool by binded key.

---

### Implementation

**ControlsPoolControl**

```
public class ControlsPoolControl<T> : UserControl where T : UIElement
{
    private readonly Panel _mainPanel;
    private T _innerControl;

    public ControlsPoolControl()
    {
        _mainPanel = new Grid();
        Content = _mainPanel;
    }

    #region Properties

    #region DependencyProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyObject", typeof(object), typeof(ControlsPoolControl<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null, KeyObjectChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PoolProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Pool", typeof(IControlsPool<T>), typeof(ControlsPoolControl<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null, PoolChanged));

    #endregion

    public object KeyObject
    {
        get { return GetValue(KeyObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public IControlsPool<T> Pool
    {
        get { return (IControlsPool<T>)GetValue(PoolProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PoolProperty, value); }
    }

    protected T InnerControl
    {
        get { return _innerControl; }
        set
        {
            if (_innerControl == value)
                return;

            _innerControl = value;
            OnControlChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private API

    void Clear()
    {
        _mainPanel.Children.Clear();
    }

    void OnKeyObjectChanged()
    {
        UpdateControl();
    }

    void OnControlChanged()
    {
        VerifyAccess();
        Clear();

        var ctrl = InnerControl;
        if (ctrl != null)
            _mainPanel.Children.Add(ctrl);
    }

    private void UpdateControl()
    {
        if (KeyObject == null || Pool == null)
            InnerControl = null;
        else
            InnerControl = Pool.Get(KeyObject);
    }

    private static void KeyObjectChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ControlsPoolControl<T>)d).OnKeyObjectChanged();
    }

    private static void PoolChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ControlsPoolControl<T>)d).UpdateControl();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**ControlsPool**

```
public interface IControlsPool<T> where T : UIElement
{
    void Add(object key, T control);
    T Get(object key);
}

public class ControlsPool<T> : IControlsPool<T> where T : UIElement
{
    readonly IDictionary<object, T> _controls = new Dictionary<object, T>();

    public void Add(object key, T control)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        if (_controls.ContainsKey(key)) return;
        _controls.Add(key, control);
    }

    public T Get(object key)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        T control = null;
        if (!_controls.TryGetValue(key, out control))
        {
            control = CreateInstance(key);
            _controls.Add(key, control);
        }

        return control;
    }

    protected virtual T CreateInstance(object key)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

### Usage

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ContentControlType = typeof(MyButton);

        Layout1 = (DataTemplate)FindResource("_layout1");
        Layout2 = (DataTemplate)FindResource("_layout2");

        DataContext = new ViewModel { Content1 = "Content1", Content2 = "Content2" };
    }

    public Type ContentControlType { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _view.ContentTemplate = _view.ContentTemplate == Layout1 ? Layout2 : Layout1;
    }

    DataTemplate Layout1;
    DataTemplate Layout2;
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public string Content1 { get; set; }
    public string Content2 { get; set; }
}

public class ButtonsPool : ControlsPool<MyButton> { }

public class ButtonPoolControl : ControlsPoolControl<MyButton>
{
}

public class MyButton : Button
{
    static int _counter = 0;

    public MyButton()
    {
        _counter++;
    }
}
```

**XAML**
To initialize reusable control, you should use style.

```
<Window Name="_mainForm" x:Class="WpfVideo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WpfVideo" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <model:ButtonsPool x:Key="_buttonsPool"/>
        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="_layout1" DataType="{x:Type model:ViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <model:ButtonPoolControl KeyObject="{Binding Content1}" Pool="{StaticResource _buttonsPool}">
                    <model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="model:MyButton">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content1}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                </model:ButtonPoolControl>
                <model:ButtonPoolControl KeyObject="{Binding Content2}" Pool="{StaticResource _buttonsPool}">
                    <model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="model:MyButton">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content2}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                </model:ButtonPoolControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="_layout2" DataType="{x:Type model:ViewModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <model:ButtonPoolControl Pool="{StaticResource _buttonsPool}" KeyObject="{Binding Content1}">
                    <model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="model:MyButton">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content1}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                </model:ButtonPoolControl>
                <model:ButtonPoolControl Pool="{StaticResource _buttonsPool}" KeyObject="{Binding Content2}">
                    <model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="model:MyButton">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content2}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </model:ButtonPoolControl.Resources>
                </model:ButtonPoolControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Change</Button>
        <ContentPresenter Name="_view" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource _layout1}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I was able to use this solution successfully. I added the following to `OnControlChanged` to handle disconnecting the child control from its parent (I'm not thrilled with this solution but it was practical for us).

`((ctrl as FrameworkElement)?.Parent as Panel)?.Children.Remove(ctrl);
if ((ctrl as FrameworkElement)?.Parent is ContentControl contentControl)
{
    contentControl.Content = null;
}

if ((ctrl as FrameworkElement)?.Parent is Decorator decorator)
{
    decorator.Child = null;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. `FrameworkElement` and `FrameworkContentElement` instances can only be added to one point of the logical tree. If you attempt to add *the same instance* of such an object to two different places you 'll get an exception saying:

> Element already has a logical parent.
>   It must be detached from the old
>   parent before it is attached to a new
>   one.

Comment: See EDITED in my post please. I think there no problem with same instance in different points of logical tree.

Comment: Changing DataTemplate creates new buttons each time when I initialize property ContentTemplate for _view, even through used old instance of datatemplate (_layout1 or _layout2).